# How to get rid of " around my string in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

When I get the token with these rules

```
STRINGA :   '"' (options {greedy=false;}: ESC | .)* '"';
STRINGB :   '\'' (options {greedy=false;}: ESC | .)* '\'';
```

it ends up grabbing `'text'` instead of just `text`.  I can easily remove the `'` and `'` myself but was wondering how I can get ANTLR to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some custom code for that. Also, you shouldn't be using a `.` (dot) inside the rule: you should explicitly define you want to match everything *except* a **backslash** (assuming that is what your `ESQ` starts with), a **quote** and **line break chars** probably.

Something like this would do it:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : STRING EOF {System.out.println($STRING.text);}
 ;

STRING
 : '"' (ESQ | ~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n'))* '"'
   {
     String matched = getText();
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

     for(int i = 1; i < matched.length() - 1; i++) {
       char ch = matched.charAt(i);
       if(ch == '\\') {
         i++;
         ch = matched.charAt(i);
         switch(ch) {
           case 'n': builder.append('\n'); break;
           case 't': builder.append('\t'); break;
           default: builder.append(ch); break;
         }
       }
       else {
         builder.append(ch);
       }
     }

     setText(builder.toString());
   }
 ;

fragment ESQ
 : '\\' ('n' | 't' | '"' | '\\')
 ;
```

If you now parse the input `"tabs:'\t\t\t'\nquote:\"\nbackslash:\\"`, the following will be printed to the console:

```
tabs:'         '
quote:"
backslash:\
```

To keep the grammar clean, you could of course move the code in a custom method:

```
grammar T;

@lexer::members {
  private String fix(String str) {
    ...
  }
}

parse
 : STRING EOF {System.out.println($STRING.text);}
 ;

STRING
 : '"' (ESQ | ~('"' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n'))* '"' {setText(fix(getText()));}
 ;

fragment ESQ
 : '\\' ('n' | 't' | '"' | '\\')
 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define the string contents as a separate category, for example

```
STRINGA : '"' STRINGCONTENTS '"';
STRINGB : '\'' STRINGCONTENTS '\'';
```

then capture the STRINGCONTENTS value.